# epsilon-SVR with LIBSVM

Tags: java, time-series, svm, libsvm, forecasting

I am trying to forecast univariate time series (my data is composed by two columns, a timestamp and a numeric value) using epsilon-SVR from LIBSVM in Java.

When I do not use features, considering only the array index as feature (which I know it is not trustworthy) it returns always the same value. If I use a sliding window, i.e, the features to predict the value at time t are the values at time t-1,t-2,..., t-sliding_window, it always returns NaN.

I do as above to train the model:

```
public svm_model train(double[] series, int svmType, int kernelType, int degree, double gamma, double coef0, double C, double eps, double p, int shrinking, int nFeatures)
{
    series = normalize(series)
    svm_parameter params = new svm_parameter();
    svm_problem problem = new svm_problem();
    svm_node node = null;
    //----------Set parameters----------
    params.svm_type  = svmType;
    params.kernel_type = kernelType;
    params.degree = degree;
    params.gamma = 1/nFeatures;
    params.coef0 = coef0;
    params.C = C;
    params.eps = eps;
    params.cache_size=100;
    params.p = p;
    params.shrinking= shrinking;
    //----------Define problem----------
    problem.l = series.length;
    problem.y = series;
    problem.x = new svm_node[series.length][];
    for(int i=0;i<series.length;i++)
    {
       problem.x[i] = new svm_node[1];
       node = new svm_node();
       node.index = 0;
       node.value = i;
       problem.x[i][0] = node;
     }
    //----------Generate model----------
    svm_model svm_model = svm.svm_train(problem,params);
    return svm_model;
}



public svm_model trainSlidingWindow(double[] series, int svmType, int kernelType, int degree, double gamma, double coef0, double C, double eps, double p, int shrinking, int nFeatures, int slidingWindow)
{
    series = normalize(series)
    svm_parameter params = new svm_parameter();
    svm_problem problem = new svm_problem();
    svm_node node = null;
    //----------Set parameters----------
    params.svm_type  = svmType;
    params.kernel_type = kernelType;
    params.degree = degree;
    params.gamma = 1/nFeatures;
    params.coef0 = coef0;
    params.C = c;
    params.eps = eps;
    params.cache_size=100;
    params.p=p;
    params.shrinking= shrinking;
    //----------Define problem----------
    problem.l = series.length;
    problem.y = series;
    problem.x = new svm_node[series.length][slidingWindow];
    for(int i=0;i<series.length;i++)
    {
       problem.x[i] = new svm_node[slidingWindow];
       for(int j=0; j<slidingWindow;j++)
       {
          node = new svm_node();
          node.index = slidingWindow-(j+1);
          if(i-(j+1) <0)
             node.value = Double.NaN;
          else
             node.value = series[i-(j+1)];
             problem.x[i][j] = node;
       }
    }
   //----------Generate model----------
   svm_model svm_model = svm.svm_train(problem,params);
   return svm_model;
}
```

The forecasts are obtained as follows:

```
public double[] predict(double[] series, svm_model model, int steps)
{
    series = normalize(series);
    double[] yPred = new double[steps];
    for(int i=0;i<steps;i++)
    {
        svm_node[] nodes = new svm_node[1];
        svm_node node = new svm_node();
        node.index = 0;
        node.value = series.length + i;
        nodes[0] = node;
        yPred[i] = svm.svm_predict(model,nodes);
    }
    return denormalize(yPred);
}

public double[] predictSlidingWindow(double[] series, svm_model model, int steps, int slidingWindow)
{
    series = normalize(series);
    double[] yPred = new double[steps];
    double[] aux = new double[slidingWindow+steps];
    System.arraycopy(series,series.length-slidingWindow,aux,0, slidingWindow);
    for(int i=0;i<steps;i++)
    {
        svm_node[] nodes = new svm_node[slidingWindow];
        for(int j=0;j<slidingWindow;j++)
        {
            svm_node node = new svm_node();
            node.index = slidingWindow-(j+1);
            node.value = aux[i+j];
            nodes[j] = node;
        }
        yPred[i] = svm.svm_predict(model,nodes);
        aux[slidingWindow+i] = yPred[i];
    }
    return denormalize(yPred);
}
```

What am I doing wrong ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, normalizing the data and changing the value of the gamma parameter to 1 solved the problem.

When the data domain is too big, it is a good approach to normalize it when building support vector regression models, improving the quality of the forecasts and the execution time.